# Attach drop event to a ui-hook instance

Tags: meteor

I am using the gwendall:ui-hooks' package and it works fine.(rendered with animation as expected on an event that changes the inside "find()" reactive var.).
My problem is that I didn't find a way to re render the template after dropping an element (part of drag and drop events). I get the method callback after the drop and I can see the sortId was replaced as expected, but the whole list is not rendered again sorted as expected.
So my question is if I can somehow add a "drop" event to the uihooks instance, so i can re build the template as in insert?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's an option:

```
Session.setDefault('isDropped', false);
```

//event on drop:

```
Session.set('isDropped', true);
```

//on the uihooks helper:

```
move: function(node, next, tpl) {
            if(Session.get('isDropped')){
                $(node)......   ;
                Session.set('isDropped', false);
```

Thanks.